# Объединение в строку значений из массива json объектов в бд Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

Имеется колонка с подобными значениями:

```
[
  {a:'text1', b: 'text2'},
  {a:'text1', b: 'text2'},
  {a:'text1', b: 'text2'},
  {a:'text1', b: 'text2'},
]
```

Пытаюсь придумать запрос для выбора значений по ключу **b** и объединения значений в строку.

В результате запроса хочу видеть: "text2 text2 text2 text2"

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE test (val json);

INSERT INTO test (val) SELECT '{"a":"text11", "b": "text21"}'::JSON;
INSERT INTO test (val) SELECT '{"a":"text12", "b": "text22"}'::JSON;
INSERT INTO test (val) SELECT '{"a":"text13", "b": "text23"}'::JSON;
INSERT INTO test (val) SELECT '{"a":"text14", "b": "text24"}'::JSON;

SELECT STRING_AGG(JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(val,'b'), ' ') result
FROM test;

          result
---------------------------
text21 text22 text23 text24
```

Comment: не набор строчек а массив объектов в одной ячейке

Comment: Какая разница? подход тот же. Разбираешь массив на отдельные объекты или записи (json_array_elements или json_populate_recordset), результат используешь в качестве источника данных.